what version of .net does the SharePoint.Client in NuGet suppport
I'm trying to get the SharePoint.Client nuget package to install into a new test project.  The project is vb.net using winform. I've .Net 7.0 and 8.0.  I've tried looking at the nuget site but they don't say anything about it either.  Can someone point me in the right direction.
For what it's worth I'm looking into grabbing a listing of the folders and directories in the sharepoint sites and a particular folder.  If I should be using something different than SharePoint.Client i'd be interested in the pointer.
Thank you

Given that the Last Updated date of that package is earlier than the release date of .NET Core 1.0, I suspect that it only supports .NET Framework. It was released between .NET Framework 4.6.1 and 4.6.2.
